# The intersection of the conjugates of $H\leq G$ is *exactly* the union of the conjugacy classes of $G$ that are fully in $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

There are several posts discussing the intersection of the conjugates of a subgroup, but I think this provides at least *something* new in this forum. I'd like to know if the reasoning and conclusion are valid, and whether or not this follows trivially from some other conclusion made elsewhere.

---

Assume the following:

- $H\leq G$ is a subgroup.
- $N:=\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$ is the group intersection of all conjugates in $G$ of $H$.
- $C:=\bigcup_{i\in I}C_i$ is the set union of all conjugacy classes $C_i$ of $G$ where $C_i\subseteq H$.

The goal is to show that $N=_{\mathbf{Set}}C$.

---

Show that $C\subseteq N$:

- Let $Q\subseteq H$ be any set invariant under conjugation in $G$. This means that $gQg^{-1}=Q$ for all $g\in G$. Therefore, $Q$ is in all conjugates of $H$, and is thus also in $N$. This can be applied to any $C_i$ in the union $C$.

Show that $N\subseteq C$:

- Let $x\in N$. If $g^{-1}xg\in H$ for all $g\in G$, then the conjugacy class of $x$ is also in $H$. Equivalently, we can show that $x\in gHg^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$. By definition of $N$, this is true for any choice of $g$; therefore, the conjugacy class of $x$ is contained in $H$, thereby also including that class in $C$.

Since $C\subseteq N$ and $N\subseteq C$, we can conclude that $N=_{\mathbf{Set}}C$. $\square$

---

At the very least, this shows that if $H$ contains a nontrivial conjugacy class then $N$ is also nontrivial. I'm fine with that result because it puts a lower bound on what $N$ can be. On the other hand, it implies that in many cases $H$ might already be normal if it contains a nontrivial conjugacy class. (Perhaps this is common for permutation groups? Seems plausible.)

Comment: This is true (and you don't need to assume that $H$ is a subgroup, it's true for $H$ an arbitrary subset) but it doesn't seem particularly easy to show that $H$ contains a nontrivial conjugacy class so I don't know what use it might have. To my mind a much more useful characterization of $N$, which can often be used to calculate it immediately, is that it's the kernel of the action of $G$ on $G/H$. In particular $G$ acts faithfully on $G/H$ iff $N$ is trivial.

Comment: What is the meaning of $G/H$ when $H$ isn't normal? Is it just an arbitrary choice of left or right cosets?

Comment: $G/H$ is the *set* of left cosets $\{gH \mid g \in G\}$. The action of $G$ on $G/H$ is defined by $g \cdot (g' H) = (gg') H$ (and now argue that this action is well-defined).

Answer (score 2):

First, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ since:
$$gNg^{-1}=g \bigg(\bigcap_{x \in G} xHx^{-1} \bigg) g^{-1} = \bigcap_{x \in G} (gx)H(gx)^{-1}=\bigcap_{x \in G} xHx^{-1}=N$$
We also have by definition that $N \leqslant H$. Moreover, for any $K \unlhd G$ and $K \leqslant H$, we have:
$$K = \bigcap_{g \in G} gKg^{-1} \leqslant \bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}=N \implies K \leqslant N$$

Clearly, all the conjugacy classes of $G$ that $N$ is a union of, must be subsets of $H$, and thus, $N \subseteq C$. To show that $N=C$, it suffices to show that for every conjugacy class $C'$ that is a subset of $H$, there exists $K \unlhd G$ such that $C' \subseteq K$. This would force $K \leqslant N$ and in turn, $C' \subseteq N$, as required.

Define $K$ as:
$$K=\bigcap_{g \in G} g \langle C' \rangle g^{-1}$$
As $K$ is the intersection of groups, we must have $K$ to be a group. Since $K$ is a subgroup of $\langle C' \rangle$, we have $K \leqslant H$. Moreover, $K$ is the intersection of conjugate groups, and thus must be normal. Finally, we can see that $C' \subseteq K$ since: $$C' = \bigcap_{g \in G} gC'g^{-1} \subseteq \bigcap_{g \in G} g \langle C' \rangle g^{-1} =  K$$

Hence, proved.

Comment: You glossed over what makes $C$ a group, i.e., how you know it's closed.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry My answer has been modified appropriately. Thanks for the query.